# Can't change <button>'s "type" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome

On Chromium 7.0.517.44 (64615) Ubuntu 10.10, I seem to be unable to change the `type` attribute of a `<button>` element:

```
> blah = document.createElement("button")
  <button>​</button>​
> blah.type
  "submit"
> blah.type = "button"
  "button"
> blah.type
  "submit"
```

Help?

---

On Firefox 3.6.12 and Opera 10.63, it works fine:

```
>>> blah = document.createElement("button")
    <button>
>>> blah.type
    "submit"
>>> blah.type = "button"
    "button"
>>> blah.type
    "button"
```

Comment: I don't believe you SHOULD be able to. Firefox and Opera let you, Chrome doesn't, but I think IE will implode. I know it does for `<input/>` so I don't think `<button>` will be any different.

Comment: @Robert: You _should_ be able to set the `type` attribute when dynamically creating new elements with script (`createElement`) - as appears to be the case above. Setting the `type` property has been fixed in Chrome and IE9, but IE8 and earlier 'implodes'. `setAttribute` resolves this (as stated in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `setAttribute`.

```
blah.setAttribute('type', 'button');
```

Comment: `Error: type property can't be changed`

Answer (score 2):

Change the `type` attribute on any of the input family generally doesn't work (I know for a fact it does not work on `input`).

What you may want to do is clone the element, replace the `type` attribute whilst the HTML is serialised and then append it after. Then delete the original.

Answer (score 2):

======================================================================

### **javascript:**

```
  function submit_button(){

      var btn=document.getElementById(button_id');
      btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');

  }
```

======================================================================

### **Jquery:**

```
 function submit_button(){

 $('#' + button_id).prop('type', 'submit');

   }
```

======================================================================

[here it works.....](http://jsfiddle.net/saidesh/3GVSP/7/)