# How to set button type from JavaScript to avoid exception in ipad's safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, button

I do this:

```
var b = document.createElement('button');
try{
    b.type = 'button';
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

On ipad's safari (ios 6.0) the alert shows 'TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.'

Works well in Firefox (no exception). What would be the cross-browser way of doing this from JavaScript? I guess I have to set the button type, according to W3C and MDN, because the default type is usually 'submit', and I want type 'button'.

-- EDIT --

b.setAttribute('type','button') works, but so does b.setAttribute('typo','button'). I've submitted a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882541/check-whether-an-attribute-is-valid-for-an-element-with-pure-javascript).

Comment: Have you tried [`b.setAttribute('type', 'button')`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170557/cant-change-buttons-type-with-javascript) ?