# Check whether an attribute is valid for an element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

My program dynamically sets attributes on DOM elements. I want to prevent setting incorrect attributes. E.g.:

```
function set(element,name,value){
    if(name is a bad attribute for element)
      throw 'problem';
    element.setAttribute(name,value);
}
```

I thought I could use hasAttribute to verify attribute names before setting them, but I can't, because it returns false before I set the attribute first time even for valid attributes. So both things here give false:

```
button.hasAttribute('typo');
button.hasAttribute('type');
```

How could I verify that an attribute name is valid?

Comment: Button has the `type` property (set to 'submit'), but not the attribute, by default.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between **properties** and **attributes**.  Things like `type`, `src`, `href`, `name`, `id`, `for`, and so on are *properties* of DOM elements. Most modern browsers will let you get and set them with `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` but there's absolutely no need to do that, and it won't work in old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well, I use setAttribute because button.type='button' throws an exception on iPad's Safari. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881229/how-to-set-button-type-from-javascript-to-avoid-exception-in-ipads-safari)